# Rendering to a texture with blending and large component sizes and OpenGLES3.1

Tags: opengl-es

I'm trying to perform a render-to-texture operation that is supposed to accumulate arithmetic calculations in a texture. The output texture format should have at least the following capabilities:

- Must have at least 2 components: One for the calculation result, one for alpha.
- The calculation result has a value range of 0-65536.
- Must be able to perform additive blending on these values using at least the alpha value from the fragment shader (blend function will be GL_ONE, GL_SRC_ALPHA).

Usually, I render to a texture using FBOs. However, according to

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

texture formats are either not color-renderable (so no FBOs) or non-blendable (because integer) or have small component sizes (usually 8-bit).

Is there a texture format that suits my needs? Or is there a non-FBO solution?

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure if this is helpful at all, but you could use multiple render targets?

Comment: In theory, but how would that help? So I could convert the numbers to something else that supports blending but needs more memory?